# Trigonometry problem: how to measure height of building when you don't see the base?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

We just bought an instrument that allows us to take height measurements. The problem is that to be able to take a height measurement, you need to point the laser at the base (m1) of the object and then at the top (m2) (see image, object A) to get h1.

We want to be able to measure height of objects for which we don't see the base (image, object B).

Is it possible using trigonometry to retrieve the height of the object B?

[image]

Comment: Not in general, no.  For instance, what if B were on a hill and its base was actually a kilometer below the base of A?  There would be no way to produce this information given the lines of sight

Comment: Actually, this is to measure parts of buildings that are higher than other parts of the same building. Given that, I consider that the building have the same elevation for all parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Position yourself as in the following picture. [image]

Then $h_2$ can be calculated by the intercept theorem:
$$h_2=h_1 \frac{l_2}{l_1} .$$

Thus the total height of the second building is given by
$$ h_0+h_1\frac{l_2}{l_1}.$$